# Get name of a function argument

Tags: llvm

I am creating an LLVM pass and I don't understand something : when I look into the .ll file the argument of a function has a name :

```
call void @_ZNK2xi9spawnable9SpawnableIFvbdEEclEbd( %"class.xi::spawnable::Spawnable.0"* nonnull @_ZN2xi9spawnable2f2E, i1 zeroext %9, double %10)
```

So here the first argument name seems to be `_ZN2xi9spawnable2f2E`.

But in my pass when I use the function `getName()` it returns me an empty string. When I access the full argument I obtain : `%"class.xi::spawnable::Spawnable.0"* %1`

How can I obtain the same name as in the .ll file?

EDIT: This is a part of the code (I tried to clean it up a little so maybe there are some missing brackets)

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
  LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();
  std::string Name = demangle(F.getName ());     
  outs() << "Function "<< *(F.getFunctionType()) <<" " << Name << " {\n";
  for(LoopInfo::iterator i = LI.begin(), e = LI.end(); i!=e; ++i)
    BlocksInLoop (*i,0);
  for( Function::iterator b = F.begin() , be = F.end() ;b != be; ++b){
    for(BasicBlock::iterator i = b->begin() , ie = b->end();i != ie; ++i){
      if(isa<CallInst>(&(*i)) || isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i))){
        if (!(i->getMetadata("seen"))){
          Function * fct =NULL;
          if (isa<CallInst>(&(*i)))
            fct = cast<CallInst>(&(*i))->getCalledFunction();
          if (isa<InvokeInst>(&(*i)))
            fct = cast<InvokeInst>(&(*i))->getCalledFunction(); 
          if (fct){
            outs()<<"Call " << *(fct->getFunctionType()) <<" "<< demangle(fct->getName()) << "\n";
          for(Function::arg_iterator argi=fct->arg_begin(),arge=fct->arg_end(); argi!=arge;argi++ )
            outs()<< argi->getName()<<"\n";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  outs() << "}\n";
  return(false);
};
```

Comment: How do you access it?

Comment: @arrowd Yes how can I access the name with my pass?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are analyzing not the call site, but the function itself. When you are looking at the function, you only have formal parameters and can't know what values are passed there.

Instead of calling `->getCalledFunction()` and iterating over its args, you should iterate over `cast<CallInst>(&(*i))` operands. See `->op_begin()` and `value_op_begin()` methods.

Comment: It does give me the name of the argument but it also return a lot more than this. Is it possible to have only the arguments of the call?